# Question on the coefficient of the Dirichlet series related to $\frac{\zeta(s+2)}{\zeta(s)}$

Tags: number-theory, dirichlet-series, mobius-inversion, dirichlet-convolution

This question is about the evaluation of $a(n)$ defined in (1) below which is related to the Riemann zeta function $\zeta(s)$ as illustrated in (2) below.

---

**(1)** $\quad a(n)=\sum\limits_{d|n}\frac{\mu\left(\frac{n}{d}\right)}{d^2}=\frac{A046970(n)}{n^2}$

**(2)** $\quad \frac{\zeta(s+2)}{\zeta(s)}=\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty a(n)\ n^{-s}\,,\quad\Re(s)>\frac{1}{2}\quad\text{(assuming Riemann hypothesis)}$

---

[A046970](https://oeis.org/A046970)  in formula (1) above is the Dirichlet inverse of the [Jordan totient function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jordan%27s_totient_function) $J_2(n)$ ([A007434](https://oeis.org/A007434)) where $J_k(n)$ is a generalization of the [Euler totient function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_totient_function) $\phi(n)$ which are both defined below.

---

**(3)** $\quad\phi(n)=n\prod\limits_{p|n}\left(1-\frac{1}{p}\right)$

**(4)** $\quad J_k(n)=n^k\prod\limits_{p|n}\left(1-\frac{1}{p^k}\right)$

---

The following figure illustrates $a(n)$ always seems to evaluate such that $-1<a(n)<1$ except at $n=1$ where $a(1)=1$, and there is also a noticeable banding in the values of $a(n)$.

---

[image: Discrete Plot of a(n)]

**Figure (1)**: Discrete Plot of $a(n)$

---

> **Question (1)**: Can it be proven that $-1<a(n)<1$ for all $n>1$? I've verified $-1<a(n)<1$ for $1<n\le 10^6$.

---

> **Question (2)**: Is there an explanation for the noticeable banding in the values of $a(n)$ in Figure (1), and does this banding pattern continue as $n\to\infty$?

Comment: Trivial property of multiplicative functions such that $a(p)= p^{-2}-1$ and $\lim_{k\to \infty} a(p^k)=0$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $f(n)$ is multiplicative, then
$$
\sum_{d|n}\mu(d)f(d)=\sum_{p|n}[1-f(p)]
$$

As a result, we have

$$
a(n)={1\over n^2}\sum_{d|n}\mu(d)d^2={1\over n^2}\sum_{p|n}(1-p^2)
$$

Let $n$ be factorized as $\prod_{p|n}p^{e_p}$ then
$$
|a(n)|=\left|\sum_{p|n}p^{-2e_p}(1-p^2)\right|=\prod_{p|n}p^{-2e_p}|p^{-2}-1|=\prod_{p|n}p^{2-2e_p}|1-p^{-2}|
$$
Since $p^{2-2e_p}\le1$ and $|1-p^{-2}|<1$, we have $|a(n)|<1$. Since $a(n)\in\mathbb R$, this can be re-expressed as
$$
-1<a(n )<1
$$